# How to put web scraped data into a csv file

Tags: python, csv

I have scraped data (basically the train details like No, Name, Type, Zone etc) from a website using the below code in jupyter notebook:

How can I put the result obtained in 'output' into a DataFrame and then into a csv file?

```
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup   
import pandas as pd

r=requests.get("https://indiarailinfo.com/arrivals/kanpur-central-cnb/452")
print(r.text[0:200000])

soup=BeautifulSoup(r.text,'html.parser')
results=soup.find_all('div',attrs={'class':'tdborder'})
results1=soup.find_all('div',attrs={'class':'tdborderhighlight'}) //for 'To' and 'Sch'
lresult=results[11:570]
lresult

for i in range(11,550):
    output=lresult[i].text
print(output)
```

Comment: Post the code in correct format, not as regular text

Comment: What does this currently output? Are you having problems using pandas?

Comment: It gives me the following output: 12381 //No.
Poorva Express (via Gaya) (PT) //Name
SF//Type
ER //Zone
1 //PF
 M  TF  //Arrival Days 
HWH   //from
08:15   //Sch
no arr today  
no arr today
n/a
11015
Kushinagar Express (PT)
Exp
CR
6
SMTWTFS
LTT
22:45
57m late
01:07
GKP/Gorakhpur Junction
59386-Slip2
Penchvalley Passenger Slip2 (Chhindwara - Gorakhpur)
Pass
CR
7
S TW  S
CWA
21:05
n/a
n/a
n/a   and so on.....

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm not entirely sure how you want the output csv to look like, but you could try something like this to convert your data to a dataframe, then output to a csv:

```
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import pandas as pd

url = 'https://indiarailinfo.com/arrivals/kanpur-central-cnb/452'

html = requests.get(url).text

soup = BeautifulSoup(html, 'lxml')
res = soup.find_all('div',attrs={'class':'tdborder'})

headers = [header.text.strip() for header in res[:11]]

lines = [[x.text.strip() for x in res[11:][i:i+11]] for i in range(0, len(res[11:]), 11)]

df = pd.DataFrame(lines, columns=headers)

df.to_csv('trains.csv', encoding='utf-8', index=False)

print(open('trains.csv', 'r').read())
```

Which gives this csv:

```
No.,Name,Type,Zone,PF,Arrival Days,From,Sch,Delay,ETA,LKL
12303,Poorva Express (via Patna) (PT),SF,ER,1,S TW  S,HWH,08:05,3h 53m late,03:58,DER/Dadri
12381,Poorva Express (via Gaya) (PT),SF,ER,1,M  TF,HWH,08:15,no arr today,no arr today,n/a
11015,Kushinagar Express (PT),Exp,CR,6,SMTWTFS,LTT,22:45,57m late,01:07,GKP/Gorakhpur Junction
...
```

Comment: how can i add for 'to and 'sch' as well?

Answer (score 0):

You need to dump every thing in a numpy arrange (easiest way) 
Then use the object to export it
EXAMPLE

```
import numpy
a = numpy.asarray([ [1,2,3], [4,5,6], [7,8,9] ])
numpy.savetxt("foo.csv", a, delimiter=",").
```

Comment: unable to get desired output

Comment: how can i put the results in 'output' into numpy arrange? I need to scrape the data every 5 minutes so putting in the output manually into the array every 5 minutes will be impossible